# How do you integrate this tensor?

Tags: integration, tensors, fluid-dynamics

The original math can be found here [Original Derivation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301874096_Emergent_behavior_in_active_colloids/link/5730bb3608ae08415e6a7c0a/download).

My question is how does one derive expression (9)? In other words the equation
$$v({\textbf{r}})={f \over{8\pi \eta r}}[\textbf{e}+(\hat{r} \cdot \textbf{e})\hat{r}]$$
where $r=|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|$ and $\hat{r}={(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0) \over r}$. We are given the expression

$$v(\textbf{r})=\int O(\textbf{r-r}')\textbf{f}(\textbf{r}')d^3x'$$
where the Oseen tensor $O(\textbf{r})={1\over 8\pi\eta}({1\over|\textbf{r}|}I+{\textbf{r}\otimes \textbf{r} \over|\textbf{r}|^3})$ and $\textbf{f}=f\textbf{e}\delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0)$. I think the confusion lies in the integral itself, and how exactly that integral equals expression (9) after substitution of the other things in?

Comment: Dropping the $\frac{f}{8\pi\eta}\boldsymbol{e}$ factor, your aim is$$\int\left(\frac{1}{\left|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}^{\prime}\right|}I+\frac{\left(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}^{\prime}\right)\otimes\left(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}^{\prime}\right)}{\left|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}^{\prime}\right|^{3}}\right)\delta\left(\boldsymbol{r}^{\prime}-\boldsymbol{r}_{0}\right)d^{3}\boldsymbol{r}^{\prime}=\frac{1}{r}\left[I+\hat{r}\otimes\hat{r}\right].$$What do you know about the Dirac delta? (Should $r_0$ be $r^\prime$?)

Comment: Just that it will mean $r'=r_0$, else the entire expression is equal to zero.

Comment: Now if you express $r,\,\hat{r}$ in terms of $\boldsymbol{r},\,\boldsymbol{r}_0$...

Comment: I tried that, but I still don't see how that integral equals what it does? Obviously, there's vectors in there, absolute values, tensor product etc which make it different from any standard integral. I think the confusion lies there